# Google Analytics Duplicate Transaction

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have an e-commerce site built on Nuxt.js and tracking set up in Google Tag Manager with Analytics. Whenever someone checks out, on the confirmation page I push to the dataLayer the checkout event (code below).

My problem is that sometimes the transaction is duplicated, sometimes the next day. The  confirmation page cannot be reloaded or revisited and I get about 2 or 3 duplicates a week. I have seen creating custom tasks in analytics to prevent duplicate transactions but thought there has to be a simpler answer.

```js
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
    'checkout': {
      'id': product.id,
      'name': product.name,
      'category': product.category,
      'price': product.price.replace(/,/g, ""),
      'quantity': 1
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: I usually see this happen because of a reload on the page. Is there no way for the user to trigger another datalayer.push for the same transaction? (reload, navigate to a history that triggers the event, something like that)

Comment: Nope, you cannot go back or reload the page.

Comment: I can't say for sure what's happening. In theory it should work, but there must be something causing a second trigger of the event. You could try to save the last transaction id as a cookie after sending the event, and add a condition to your trigger so that it doesn't fire when the cookie value equals the dataLayer value. It's not the native way, but it should deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some users the it was caching the ecommerce object and pushing on other events. To avoid this I just put the following code after pushing my purchase event:

```
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });
```